# Find longest common prefix?

Tags: java

In two strings:

> "Mary Had a Little Lamb" 
> "Mary Had a Big Lamb"

should return

> "Mary Had a "

Comment: The example that is given here is very easy to understand but if the string is "ababac" then how could I find out longest common prefix?

Answer (score 40):

You don't need to use a `StringBuilder` - just return the substring:

```
public String greatestCommonPrefix(String a, String b) {
    int minLength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) {
            return a.substring(0, i);
        }
    }
    return a.substring(0, minLength);
}
```

Comment: simple & elegant

Answer (score 11):

Apache Commons to the rescue!

[org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.getCommonPrefix](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getCommonPrefix-java.lang.String...-)

... and compare the [source code](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.7976) with the ingenious/valiant effort of dyross here (currently with highest vote).  But her/his code, good though it is, only handles two `String`s. This can handle any number.

Apart from not re-inventing the wheel, I can think of two reasons why using Apache Commons is always best for this sort of thing.

1. The Apache engineers can be counted on to have developed comprehensively tested code which deals with any gotchas
2. It means you don't clutter up your beautiful code with stoopid utility methods.  Instead you can get on with the, um, interesting things.

If the whole of a given Apache Commons module is really too much for your context (they're usually just a few kB, but OK) you can extract the bits you need from the source code (assuming this complies with the licence). In this case [indexOfDifference](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.7885) is an essential function...

Comment: And a corollary of your 2nd argument: it reduces your code base, which is a very good thing

Answer (score 2):

This solution applied to a multiple string array. When you have 3 or 4 strings, it's better to use StringBuilder. For 2 strings, it's ok to use substring. Code in C#:

```
    public string LongestCommonPrefix(string[] strs) {
    if(strs.Length == 0) return string.Empty;

    Array.Sort(strs);

    var first = strs[0];
    var last = strs[strs.Length - 1];

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i< first.Length; i++)
    {
        if(first[i] != last[i])
        {
            break;
        }
        sb.Append(first[i]);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why are you use builder? Operating on indexes and taking substring as result should be enough.

Comment: @TimurMilovanov good point. Just find the i that breaks the loop.

Answer (score 2):

A very easy solution can be:

```
  public static String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    if (strs.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    String result = strs[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
        while (!strs[i].startsWith(result)) {
            result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test{
 public static void main(String[] args){
    String s1 = "Mary Had a Little Lamb";
    String s2 = "Mary Had a Big Lamb";
    int minStrLen = s1.length();
    if ( minStrLen > s2.length()){
        minStrLen = s2.length();
    }

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<minStrLen; i++){
        if ( s1.charAt(i) ==  s2.charAt(i)){
         output.append(s1.charAt(i));
        }else{
          break;
        }
    }       
    System.out.println(output.toString());
  }
}
```

This may not be the optimum solution, but this is easy to understand and program.

I borrowed this idea from the list merging technique of [merge-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm. If you read little about list merging technique  you will better understand the logic of my algorithm.

Comment: You don't need a StringBuilder, just return the substring. See my solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str1;
String str2;
// assuming str1.length > str2.length
```

1. a.startsWith(b) == true
   if not
2. in a loop keep deleting last char from str1 and repeat check of step 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample code. Hope it will help you. Below is the Code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MaxPrefixString {    

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  int count = 0;

  String [] input= {"Java is a Programming Language",
                    "Java is a OO",
                    "Java is a Platform independent language",
                    "Java is a my favourite"};

  Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(input));  
  Integer [] length = new Integer[input.length];

  for(int j= 0; j<input.length ; j++){
   length[j] = input[j].length();
  }
  Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(length));

  for(int i=0;i<length[0];i++){

   if(isValidPrefix(input[0].substring(0, i), input)){
    count++;
   }else{
    break;
   }
  }
  System.out.println("Answer:"+input[0].substring(0, count-1));
 }

 private static boolean isValidPrefix(String str,String []input){
  boolean istrueForAll = true;

  for(int i = 0;i<input.length;i++){
   istrueForAll = istrueForAll && check(input[i], str);
  }
  return istrueForAll;
 }

 private static boolean check(String input,String str){
  return input.contains(str);
 }
}
```

Let me know if I missed any scenario. [click here](https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=2112002946568563457#editor/target=post;postID=7977228719114033276;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=1;src=postname)

Answer (score 0):

A very not efficient and probably might be criticised a lot. But i came up with this idea and surprisingly it satisfied all of my test cases. And it even did the work that you were intending to do. Easy to understand. Please do comment on it and let me know how i can improve it. (open to all kinds of remarks and improvement)

```
class Solution {
public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    int i;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    if(strs.length == 0 ){
        return sb.toString();
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j< strs[0].length();j++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(String word: strs){
            try{  
                word.charAt(j);  
            }catch(Exception e){
                return sb.toString();
            }      
            if(word.charAt(j) == strs[0].charAt(j) ){
                count ++;
            }else{
                return sb.toString();
            }
            if(count == strs.length){
                sb.append(word.charAt(j));
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Runtime: 2 ms, faster than 35.59% of Java online submissions for Longest Common Prefix.  Memory Usage: 37.2 MB, less than 62.51% of Java online submissions for Longest Common Prefix.
Note: Arrays.sort() will take up some additional ms than compared to manual sort!

```
    public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    
    if (strs.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    
    if (strs.length == 1) {
        return strs[0];
    }
    
    int minLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < strs.length; ++i ) {
        
        minLen = Math.min(minLen, strs[i].length());
    }
    
    int maxLen = 0;
    
    for (int i = minLen; i >= 0; --i)  {
        
        boolean areAllStringsHasSamePrefix = true;
        String prefix = strs[0].substring(0, i);
        
        for ( int j = 0; j < strs.length; ++j) {
        
            if ( !strs[j].startsWith(prefix) ) {
                areAllStringsHasSamePrefix = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if ( areAllStringsHasSamePrefix ) {
            maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, i);
        }
    }
    
    return strs[0].substring(0, maxLen);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it simple, with org.apache.commons.lang3:

1. Add the dependency:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'
```

2. Write the code:

```java
String a = "";
String b = "";
String prefix = StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(a, b);
```

Examples from the [doc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/latest/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html:), BUT noticed that in the latest version you do not need to wrap strings in array since now it takes Varargs:

```java
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(null) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"abc"}) = "abc"
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {null, null}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"", ""}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"", null}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"abc", null, null}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {null, null, "abc"}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"", "abc"}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"abc", ""}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"abc", "abc"}) = "abc"
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"abc", "a"}) = "a"
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"ab", "abxyz"}) = "ab"
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"abcde", "abxyz"}) = "ab"
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"abcde", "xyz"}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"xyz", "abcde"}) = ""
 StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(new String[] {"i am a machine", "i am a robot"}) = "i am a "
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for Kotlin

```
fun Iterable<String>.commonPrefix(ignoreCase: Boolean = false): String {
    var commonPrefix: String? = null
    for (string in this) {
        if (commonPrefix == null) {
            commonPrefix = string
            continue
        }
        commonPrefix = commonPrefix.commonPrefixWith(string, ignoreCase)
    }
    return commonPrefix ?: error("empty iterable")
}

fun String.commonPrefixWith(otherString: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): String {
    var offset = 0
    while (true) {
        val thisChar = this.getOrNull(offset) ?: break
        val otherChar = otherString.getOrNull(offset) ?: break
        if (!thisChar.equals(otherChar, ignoreCase)) {
            break
        }
        offset++
    }
    return this.substring(0, offset)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but here is how my solution looks like with time complexity O(MAX * n * log n ):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CommonPrefix {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] names = { "JavadfdTech", "JavaProgramming", "JavaBooks", "JavaGuys", "JavaLectures" };
    String commonPrefix = findCommonPrefix(names);
    System.out.println(commonPrefix);
}

static String findCommonPrefix(String [] names){
    if(names.length ==0){
        return "";
    }

    if(names.length == 1){
        return names[0];
    }

    int size = names.length;
    Arrays.sort(names);

    int end = Math.min(names[0].length(), names[size - 1].length());

    int i = 0;

    while (i < end && names[0].charAt(i) == names[size - 1].charAt(i)) {
        i += 1;
    }
    return names[0].substring(0, i);
}
```

}

Note: O(MAX * n * log n ) where n is the number of strings in the array and MAX is maximum number of characters in any string. Please note that comparison of two strings would take at most O(MAX) time and for sorting n strings, we would need O(MAX * n * log n ) time.

Answer (score -2):

Use binary search. Try to compare whole strings. If they are not equal try to compare the first characters. If they are equal try to split the strings (`substring(0, str.length()/2`). Etc, etc.

Comment: If the common prefix is n, you will need to compare the first n characters no matter what. Doing a binary search is overkill and might result in extra comparisons.