# How to find matching characters in two strings using regex java

Tags: java, regex, count, character, matching

In a given two words, is it possible to use regex to find multiple strings matching character as well index.

For example:

```
String1 = cat 
String2 = carrot
```

the first 2 characters and indexes are matching (`ca`). `t` does not count because it is not in the same index.

I've tried for loop. However it appears to be not working and not very efficient.

```
for (int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < string2.length(); j++){
        char ch1 = string1.charAt(i);
        char ch2 = string2.charAt(j);
        if (ch1 == ch2) {
            count char++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is the **longest common prefix**.

See [Find longest common prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033655/find-longest-common-prefix)

Regex is for pattern matching. It is a solution to a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

For loop can still work for this job to find positions where each string has same char and number of times this occurs:

```
ArrayList<Integer> places = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(string1.length(), string2.length()); i++) {
 a = string1.charAt(i);
 b = string2.charAt(i);
 if (a == b) {
  count++;
  places.add(i); //To say at which indices the 2 strings have the same chars
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to count the number of characters repeated at the same positions in two words. (Not same prefix)

In words `cat` `carrot`, you want to get 2 since `c` and `a` are in the same position, but `t` is not.

in words `carrot` `cabra`, you will get 3, since `c`, `a` and `r` (4th) are the same in the same position.

You only need to iterate one time over the two strings at the same time:

```java
String string1 = "car";
String string2 = "carrot";

int minLength = Math.min( string1.length(), string2.length() );

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++){
    char ch1 = string1.charAt(i);
    char ch2 = string2.charAt(i);
    if (ch1 == ch2) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

We use `minLength` since we only need to check until the length of the smallest word.

We use `string1.charAt(i)` and `string2.charAt(i)`, with same index `i`, since we want to check characters in the same position.