# Finding largest match in prefix url

Tags: java, string, url

```
var urls = List.of(
        "/a/b/c/d",
        "/a/b/a/d",
        "/a/a/c/d",
        "/q/w/e/r/");

var search = "/a/b/c/e/q";
```

I need to compare a string to a list of strings and find the largest match. Strings can contain numbers and symbols - everything that can be in url.

The **result** of the comparison between "search" and "urls" should be the answer **"/a/b/c"**.
How can I solve this using java?

Comment: What particular difficulty are you having solving this?

Answer (score 1):

This is called longest prefix matching and has an [efficient solution using a Trie data structure](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-prefix-matching-a-trie-based-solution-in-java/) if performance is important.

For a simple solution, I don't believe anything built-in is readily available. Borrowing a [longest common prefix implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8033983/7543069), the following is a straightforward iterative solution:

```java
public String greatestCommonPrefix(String a, String b) {
    int minLength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) {
            return a.substring(0, i);
        }
    }
    return a.substring(0, minLength);
}

public String longestPrefixMatch(List<String> urls, String search) {
    String prefix = "";
    for (String url : urls) {
        String match = greatestCommonPrefix(url, search);
        if (match.length() > prefix.length()) prefix = match;
    }
    return prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1); // Remove trailing '/'
}
```